# angular2-color-picker TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined - source-node.js

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

angular2-color-picker TypeError:

> Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined - source-node.js

I am getting this error while doing:

```
npm i --save angular2-color-picker
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you install

```
npm i --save angular2-color-picker
```

and get node error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined - source-node.js
```

**Go to package.json
and add

```
"config": {
    "ionic_source_map_type": "eval"
}
```

Under

```
 "cordovaPlugins": [
```